# Accommodating to changes in target of transfer properties file in soapUI

Tags: xpath, xquery, soapui

I have a script evaluation scenario where the namespaces of my request WSDL will be different only in namespace from one another, due to which the testing(by importing test suite) for the request using property transfer in soapUI is becoming difficult because i have to change my property transfer's target namespace each time because of change in namespace.My requirement is create a test suite which can work for all scenarios.Please suggest a method.

SOAPUI Version-5.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAPUI accept a `*` as a wildcard for namespaces. So if you've something like:

```
declare namespace ns='http://www.openuri.org/';
//ns:Root/ns:someNode
```

You can safety simplify your XPath to something like:

```
//*:Root/*:someNode
```

Or event shorter (if there are same node names in a different hierarchy):

```
//*:someNode
```

Since there is no sample of your user case I give you a general approach for your problem.

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:exam="http://www.example.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <exam:ProcessRequest>
         <exam:Name>Sugaraj</exam:Name>
         <exam:Age>18</exam:Age>
         <exam:State>TN</exam:State>
         <exam:Height>7</exam:Height>
         <exam:Weight>50</exam:Weight>
      </exam:ProcessRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> -> here my exam namespace is going to change dynamically.How to give xpath for this?

Comment: @SugaRaj this is your xml, can you share also your actual `Xpath`?

Comment: Thank you for the solution of using the wildcard.Its working now.

Comment: I have another question. I am exporting a testcase and importing it in another project back again. but my target property is empty in the project i imported and also my process inside testcase is disabled.How to prevent them from happening?

Comment: @SugaRaj If my answers help you to solve the problem please think about a [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). About your comment if you have another question please post as a new question instead of in the comments, this way you'll have more chances to get a good answer for it :).